# How can I get response for start and stop VM from Azure ARM java SDk?

Tags: java, azure, cloud, azure-resource-manager

I am using Azure ARM java SDK and I perform operation start and stop VM. I am not able to get the response.

```
     try{
           VirtualMachine vm=azure.virtualMachines().getByGroup("resourceGroup", "vmNAme");
            vm.start();
    }catch(CloudException| IllegalArgumentException| IOException|InterruptedException e){

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

**vm.start();** is a sysnc call. 
In Azure ASM able to get by **getVirtualMachinesOperations()** method.

Is there any way to get the response ?.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from documentation Start/Restart/Stop calls return only status code : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163628.aspx

So, start/stop/restart function are void in Java SDK.

You will find information about Virtual Machine status in the VirtualMachineInstanceView : `VirtualMachineInstanceView vmInstanceView = vm.refreshInstanceView();` or `VirtualMachineInstanceView vmInstanceView = vm.instanceView();` to optimize some calls.

Comment: It hold operation at  **vm.start()**. Yes we can get status of vm on another call. Is there any way to get status on same call (when we do call on/off vm).

Comment: @PawanSharma I do not see any other options, but you can check the implementation code for VirtualMachine class here : https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/08bd17840669bc3f235235dc270a822be852a2d5/azure-mgmt-compute/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/implementation/VirtualMachinesImpl.java

Comment: @PawanSharma There is also Azure Insights that contains all details about operations : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931934.aspx but you should implement those calls by your own cause there is no class for this in Azure Java SDK

Answer (score 0):

@PawanSharma, According to your code, I know you are using the version `1.0.0-beta` of Azure SDK for Java. If you want to get status on the start/stop call as you wish, I think the way is that directly use REST APIs with HTTP Client or return the SDK version `0.9` to get the `ComputeLongRunningOperationResponse` from the function `VirtualMachineOperations.start/startAsync`.

Hope it helps.